# How do I repeat a Reachability test until it works

Tags: xcode, reachability, viewdidload

I have an initial tableviewcontroller which is executing a reachability check. This is working without a problem within the `viewDidLoad`, **however** I would like to know the correct way to *Retry* the connection until it passes. The pertinent code in my implementation file is below, I have tried inserting `[self ViewDidLoad]` if the connection is down but this just sets the app into a loop (returning the connection failure `NSLog` message) and not showing the `UIAlertView`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(![self connected])
    {
        // not connected
        NSLog(@"The internet is down");
        UIAlertView *connectionError = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Connection      Error" message:@"There is no Internet Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Retry" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [connectionError show];
        [self viewDidLoad];
    } else
    {
        NSLog(@"Internet connection established");
        UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoDark];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(infoButtonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]    initWithCustomView:btn];
        [self start];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How should you use [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007324-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)?

- Always try your connection first.
- If the request fails, Reachability will tell you why.
- If the network comes up, Reachability will notify you. Retry the connection then.

In order to receive notifications, register for the notification, and start the reachability class from Apple:

```
@implementation AppDelegate {
    Reachability *_reachability;
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver: self
     selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:)
     name: kReachabilityChangedNotification
     object: nil];

    _reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName: @"www.apple.com"];
    [_reachability startNotifier];

    // ...
}

@end
```

To answer the notification:

```
- (void) reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification *)notification {
    Reachability *reach = [notification object];
    if( [reach isKindOfClass: [Reachability class]]) {
    }
    NetworkStatus status = [reach currentReachabilityStatus]; 
    NSLog(@"change to %d", status); // 0=no network, 1=wifi, 2=wan
}
```

If you rather use blocks instead, use [KSReachability](https://github.com/kstenerud/KSReachability).

Comment: Note: that's non ARC code. You can flag a file being not ARC by adding the Compiler Flag -fno-objc-arc in the Build Phases > Compile Sources section of your target.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, at the risk of being extremely thick, where does the first block of code go (in the viewDidLoad?)

Comment: Yes, if you want it for one view controller, or in the app delegate (see updated answer) if you want it for the whole app. Don't hesitate to ask, it all looked foreign to me when I started with Objective-C.