# How to check internet connectivity in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, nsnotificationcenter

How can I check whether the app is connected to the internet or not?
currently, I am using this code in my `appdelegate.m` file

```
dispatch_queue_t connectivityThread = dispatch_queue_create("com.gm.kart.connectivity", NULL);

dispatch_async(connectivityThread, ^{
    while (true){
        if([GMMConnectivity hasConnectivity])
            NSLog(@"%@", @"connected");
        else
            NSLog(@"Not connected");

        usleep(10000000);
    }
});
```

and when I click my login button I want to do a  check whether the internet is connected or not using `NSnotificationcenter`?

Please help me

Comment: have you search something ? http://www.google.com/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=How+to+check+internet+connectivity+in+ios%3F&oq=How+to+check+internet+connectivity+in+ios%3F&gs_l=hp.3..0i22i30l2.950.950.0.1947.1.1.0.0.0.0.173.173.0j1.1.0...0.0...1c.1.9.psy-ab.FQR8PLKiNzs&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45368065,d.bmk&fp=55f9ca2dd31d2c85&biw=1600&bih=799

Comment: tried..but nothing related to my code

Comment: I don't know GMMConnectivity, but here is how you do it with Reachability (the Apple provided class) and NSNotificationCenter: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15854823/412916

Comment: possible duplicate  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 11):

After download bellow example.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/Reachability/index.html

you can use it in your Project like bellow steps:-

`included Apple's Reachability.h & .m from their Reachability example.`

`add the SystemConfiguration framework.`

put bellow method in to your appdelegare.m file:-

```
- (BOOL) connectedToNetwork{
    Reachability* reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"google.com"];
    NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable)
    {
        isInternet =NO;
    }
    else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWWAN)
    {
        isInternet = TRUE;
    }
    else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFi)
    { isInternet = TRUE;

    }
    return isInternet;
}
```

**isInternet is a BOOL declear in to your .h class**

as per your code:-

```
dispatch_queue_t connectivityThread = dispatch_queue_create("com.GMM.assamkart.connectivity", NULL);

dispatch_async(connectivityThread, ^{
    while (true){
       isInternet =[self connectedToNetwork];
    if (isInternet)
    {
           NSLog(@"connected");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Not connected");
        }
       // usleep(10000000);
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
-(BOOL) connectedToInternet

{
    NSString *URLString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];

return ( URLString != NULL ) ? YES : NO;

}
```

Comment: This code is synchronous so it would interrupt your main thread. You'd also have to download that webpage every time you wanted to check for internet connection. Definitely use Reachability instead.